# Start an activity from code

Tags: android

I have a package name and an activity name and I want to start a new class or activity using it. Is it possible to start the activity from code without declaring the same activity in the manifest file?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can't start an activity if it isn't declared in the Manifest. All you might do is change the views programaticaly, but not the activity.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this ([see the 2nd paragraph of the Activity 'Class Overview'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.htm)). However...

1. If you want to do this to prevent people launching sub-activities directly, you can put logic in to detect the launching activity (via [Activity.getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) / [Activity.getCallingPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingPackage%28%29)) - you'll need to use StartActivityForResult to do this
2. You might be able to achieve what you want through a ClassLoader - more details on what you're doing (and why) would be useful.
3. If you're trying to launch an activity defined in a different package, then it only needs to be declared in the other package's manifest - you can then specify it with [Intent.setClassName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Yes, I want to launch activities from other package, not on the same package.

Comment: Then you don't need to reference it in your manifest. If you are explicitly calling another package, use Intent.setComponent